# jQuery add row before fourth to last row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I have an invoice table. The last four rows are as follows, starting from last: Grand Total, Tax, Subtotal, Add a line link.

So I need to add a row before the "Add a link link row".

This thread [Add table row in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171027/add-table-row-in-jquery) shows how to add a row after the last row. I just need to modify it, to add a row before the fourth to last row.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

how about you add a class to your grand total row

```
<tr class="grand-total"></tr>
```

then in jquery you do

```
$('#myTable tr.grand-total').before('<tr></tr>');
```

this way you are not doing it based on a position that might be changing, but instead based on something meaningful like 'grand total'

Answer (score 11):

You want a negative `.eq`:

```
$("#table tr").eq(-4).before(
    $("<tr>").append(
        $("<td>") // ...
    )
);
```

Comment: +1 I keep forgetting that you can use **a negative index** on the `.eq()` function. Ugh.

Comment: @Richard Neil Ilagan: Note though the *selector* (`:eq()`) does not accept negative indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Use [.before()](http://api.jquery.com/before/) instead of [.after()](http://api.jquery.com/after/):

```
$('#myTable tr:last').before('<tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr>');
```

Comment: I've obviously missed the part `starting from last`.

Answer (score 2):

You can get to the last row and then go up with **prev()**

```
$(function(){
   $("#myTable tr:last")
       .prev().prev().prev().prev()
       .after("<tr><td>x</td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: That, or `$("#myTable tr:last").prevAll().eq(2).before("...");` to avoid spamming `prev()` calls.