# JQuery Append nests new row inside existing row

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to insert a new row before the last (n-th) row in a table. However, Using the code below it instead nests the new

`<tr></tr>` inside the n-th `<tr></tr>`. Making the output look like this:

```
<tr><tr></tr></tr>
```

**This is the code:**

```
$('#sbdrp_table > tbody tr:last-child')
  .append('<tr><td>my data</td><td>more data</td></tr>');
```

**This is the outcome:**

```
<tr><td colspan="2"><input style="width: 100%" type="button" class="add-row x" value="+ Add"></td>
  <tr><td>my data</td><td>more data</td></tr>
</tr>
```

**Expected Outcome**
The new row should come before the last row.

Comment: Append to the tbody `$('#sbdrp_table > tbody').append`

Comment: @mplungjan This will add the row after the last which happens to be the "Add new row" button.

Expected Outcome should be before the last row

Comment: @mplungjan

If I use "    $('#sbdrp_table > tbody:last-child').prepend(row);" The new row is added at the beginning of <tbody> which works fine for me. Im concerned that the correct code is nesting into an existing <tr> instead of creating an entirely new <tr>

Comment: So use jQuery.before since lastChild is the last row and you append to the row, not the tbody

Comment: @mplungjan
Thank you! This worked for me:
$('#sbdrp_table > tbody tr:last').before(row);

Comment: [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523860/jquery-add-row-before-fourth-to-last-row)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery add row before fourth to last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523860/jquery-add-row-before-fourth-to-last-row)

Comment: @AlexanderNenashev Probably. II used this: $('#sbdrp_table > tbody tr:last').before(row);

So I guess that should work also.